# Parse markdown file with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file to parse through a markdown file and create a text file with the code between two specific blocks.

#### My markdown file looks as such:

```
# Dependencies
## Python Packages
- pytube==15.0.0
- moviepy==1.0.3
- keyboard==0.13.5
- pyinstaller==5.10.1
## UPX Version
- UPX==4.0.2--win64
```

I want the batch code to get the lines after *## Python Packages* and before the next *##*, ignore the hyphens, and write to a text file, *requirements.txt* that would look like:

```
pytube==15.0.0
moviepy==1.0.3
keyboard==0.13.5
pyinstaller==5.10.1
```

### To parse through the file, my batch code looks like this:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2,3" %%i in (dependencies.md) do call :process %%i %%j %%k

:process
set VAR1=%1
set VAR2=%2
@echo %VAR1%
@echo %VAR2%
```

### This outputs:

```
Dependencies
k
Python
Packages
pytube     
15.0.0     
moviepy    
1.0.3      
keyboard   
0.13.5     
pyinstaller
5.10.1     
UPX
Version
UPX
4.0.2--win64
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
```

1. I don't know how to utilize this
2. It includes unnecessary info

I was thinking parsing through everything after *Packages* and before *UPX* but that hardly seems efficient.

Normally to write to a text file I would do:

```
Set out="."
(
    Echo;pytube==15.0.0
    Echo;moviepy==1.0.3
    Echo;keyboard==0.13.5
    Echo;pyinstaller==5.10.1
) > "%out%\requirements.txt"
```

I feel like this could be solved within the for loop but I am unexperienced in batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
@echo off & setlocal

:: Empty the contents of the file - just for testing this script
type nul >"requirements.txt"

:: Unset the flag if for some reason it's been set beforehand
set dependencies=

:: Tokenize the contents - everything after the first delimiter
:: (in this case space) will be contained in the second token (%%j)
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in (dependencies.md) do (
    if "%%~i"=="##" (
        if not defined dependencies (
            set "dependencies=true"
        ) else (
            set "dependencies="
        )
    ) else if defined dependencies if "%%~i"=="-" (
        echo(%%~j
    )
) >>"requirements.txt"
```

1. Check whether the first token is `##` - if it is, set a flag.
2. If it's `##` and the flag is already set - unset it so that only the first `##` is taken into account.
3. Otherwise, if the flag is set and the first token is a hyphen, echo the contents of the second token to a file.

Comments:

- because a for loop is evaluated by the parser at once we have to check the flag through `if (not) defined` - checking `%dependencies%` would return an empty string
- `%%~j` is used instead of `%%j` in case the contents of the second token are in double quotes
- `echo(` over plain `echo` due to a [multitude of reasons](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4554#p4554)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you out?

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "_="
1>"requirements.txt" (For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1,*" %%G In ("dependencies.md") Do (
    If "%%~G" == "##" If /I "%%~H" == "Python Packages" (Set "_=T") Else Set "_="
    If Defined _ If "%%G" == "-" Echo(%%H))
```

The methodology is similar to that already proposed by mataha, the main differences being that it doesn't assume the order/position of `## Python Packages` in the file, and it opens the file for writing only once, so should be a little quicker.